# Show popup on clicking label, and change popup contents based on label

Tags: jquery, css

I have a popup which displays upon clicking any label in `#nav`; however, I want different content to appear inside depending on which label is clicked. Currently, the different popup content divs will all hide or show based off CSS only (e.g. my jQuery selector might be wrong). How do I fix this? Would I be better off adding/removing active classes instead of using a radio setup? Thanks!

UPDATE1: With the typo indicated from comments fixed, it would seem my issue now is not displaying the other, unchecked-radio targets.

UPDATE2: Adding `$('[id^="c-"]').hide();` appears to correctly display only one target div; however, it seems to require two clicks to work. (One click will display the popup's previous state, e.g. empty if nothing was clicked yet, or `#c-ask` if its label was the last one clicked.)

**HTML:**

```html
<input hidden type="radio" id="ask" name="popinfo"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="sub" name="popinfo"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="mnu" name="popinfo"/>
<div id="fade">
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="c-ask">ask</div>
        <div id="c-sub">sub</div>
        <div id="c-mnu">mnu</div>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="splash">
    <div class="info">
        // 
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <label for="ask"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></label>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <label for="sub"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></label>
        <label for="mnu"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></label>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#splash {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#ff0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align: center;
}

.info {margin: auto;}

#nav {
    margin-bottom:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#f00;
}

#c-ask, #c-sub, #c-mnu {display:none;}

#fade {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}

#popup {
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%; left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$('label').click(function(){ 
    $("#fade").fadeToggle();
    $("#popup").fadeToggle();           
    var $target = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('id');
    $('[id^="c-"]').hide();
    $("#c-" + $target).show();
});
$("#fade").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: typo near `$("#c-" + target)` should be `$("#c-" + $target)` .

Comment: @Swati Thank you for that! With that and another line I just added to the JS, a new issue has arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be better to work with `:radio` change event instead of `label` click event

```js
$('input:radio:hidden').on('change',function(){  // radio change event
    $("#fade , #popup").fadeIn();           
    var $target = $(this).attr('id'); // use $(this)
    $('[id^="c-"]').hide().filter("#c-" + $target).show();
});
$("#fade").click(function(){
    $("#fade , #popup").fadeOut();
    $('input:radio:hidden').prop('checked' , false); // when hide pop up unchecked all the radios
});

$("#popup").on('click' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#splash {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background:#ff0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align: center;
}

.info {margin: auto;}

#nav {
    margin-bottom:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#f00;
}

#c-ask, #c-sub, #c-mnu {display:none;}

#fade {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}

#popup {
    display:none;
    z-index:2;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%; left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-2XFplPlrFClt0bIdPgpz8H7ojnk10H69xRqd9+uTShA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input hidden type="radio" id="ask" name="popinfo"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="sub" name="popinfo"/>
<input hidden type="radio" id="mnu" name="popinfo"/>
<div id="fade">
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="c-ask">ask</div>
        <div id="c-sub">sub</div>
        <div id="c-mnu">mnu</div>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="splash">
    <div class="info">
        Info
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <label for="ask"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></label>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <label for="sub"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></label>
        <label for="mnu"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></label>
    </div>
</section>
```

> **Note:** Personally, I don't prefer to use the `id` as a reference .. I prefer to use `data` attributes

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'd thought `$(this)` would only target the immediately-preceding selector (e.g. `$('#popup')` here); your replacement also makes the function look nicer.

Comment: You're totally welcome @Nintendraw Have a great day :-)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry; I discovered another glitch with my jQuery. My popup may contain interactable elements (e.g. links, searchbars), but it seems that clicking anywhere within `#popup` (interactable or not) will also cause both to hide--how do I fix this? Another site I made had `#fade {pointer-events:none;}` (to which `#popup` was appended to) and turned the FA's into times icons which controlled popup/fade visibility; I wonder if I can preserve "click `#fade` not covered by `#popup` to hide both".

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` @Nintendraw .. answer updated

Comment: Thanks again! You're a life-saver. jQuery is my weakest language (among HTML/CSS/JS at least).